# How to define column as datatype of double in MDX?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm new to MDX and analysis services so bear with me. When I run the following MDX query the resulting values come back as doubles for Column A-I however the column metadata is showing the datatype as being of type object when is should be double. How do I force it to recognise the datatype to be double, can I even do that? I'm not sure how it's inferring that it is of type object.

```
WITH
        MEMBER [Column (A)] AS [Measures].[ColumnA]
        MEMBER [Column (B)] AS [Measures].[ColumnB]
        MEMBER [Column (C)] AS [Measures].[ColumnC]
        MEMBER [Column (D)] AS [Measures].[ColumnD]
        MEMBER [Column (E)] AS [Measures].[ColumnE]
        MEMBER [Column (F)] AS [Measures].[ColumnF]
        MEMBER [Column (G)] AS [Measures].[ColumnB] - [Measures].[ColumnA]
        MEMBER [Column (H)] AS [Measures].[ColumnD] - [Measures].[ColumnC]
        MEMBER [Column (I)] AS [Measures].[ColumnF] - [Measures].[ColumnE]
        SELECT 
        NON EMPTY
        {
            Column (A),
            Column (B),
            Column (C),
            Column (D),
            Column (E),
            Column (F),
            Column (G),
            Column (H),
            Column (I)
        } ON COLUMNS,
        NON EMPTY
        CROSSJOIN(
            CROSSJOIN([T].[TB].[TB],

                  [T].[TT].[TT]),

                  [T].[TR].[TR])  
        ON ROWS
        FROM RePro          
        WHERE 
        (
            [RS].[RS].[EOD],
                [RD].[RD].[DATE],
                [P].[P].[ABCD]
        )
        CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try the CDbl function. Some examples I found on it: 
[Casting nvarchar to Decimal using MDX](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/f1cb5823-4035-4b23-93ab-9c7dd564591f)  
[Mean, Median and Mode in MDX](http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/blogs/jeremykashel/archive/2012/03/19/mean-median-and-mode-in-mdx.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing some context here but are the `[Measures].[ColumnA]` themselves defined as `decimal` (or `money`)?

If they are, could you try this slight change to your MDX where instead of

```
WITH MEMBER [Column (A)] ...
```

alter it to

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Column (A)] AS [Measures].[ColumnA]
```

so that way the data type definition is propagated fully as you're keeping the same measure context.